# How to vectorize this code r code using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, vectorization

I want to know how to shorten this code by vectorizing (activities is a character vector of length 3):

```
data %>% mutate(label=recode(label, `1`=activities[1],
                                    `2`=activities[2],
                                    `3`=activities[3])) %>%
    rename_with( ~ gsub("^t", "Time", .x)) %>%
    rename_with( ~ gsub("^f", "Frequency", .x)) %>%
    rename_with( ~ gsub("Acc", "Accelerometer", .x))
```

I want something like `mutate(label=recode(label, 1:3 = activities)` and

`rename_with( ~ gsub(c("^t", ^f", "Acc"), c("Time","Frequency","Accelerometer"), .x))`, but these don't work. Thanks.

Comment: Hey. Please provide a reproducible example for us to help you. See for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: https://github.com/pskola/G-CDproject/blob/master/sample_data.txt
Here's the sample data. Is github a common place to host their examples, or should I have used something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use a named vector in `recode` to change the values

```
library(dplyr)
data %>%
       mutate(label = recode(label, !!! setNames(activities[1:3], 1:3))) %>%
       rename_at(vars(matches('^([tf]|Acc)')), 
             ~ c("Time", "Frequency", "Accelerometer"))
```

Regarding `rename_with`, the `gsub` is not vectorized for `patterns`.  Instead, we can use `str_replace`

```
library(stringr)

   ... %>%
        rename_with(~  str_replace_all(.x, setNames( c("Time","Frequency","Accelerometer"), c("^t", "^f", "Acc"))))
```

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I meant. I'm not familiar with the !!! notation. Is it a dplyr thing?

Comment: @pskola it is for splicing and doing the match with the original vector to match and replace